# Logging every API request in Ember-Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm still a bit new to Ember. I'm using Ember 1.13 with Ember Data and the DS.RESTAdapter. For debugging purposes, as well as educational (such as getting a feel for how Ember Data works with various options such as the `shouldReload*` functions), I want to log every API request with mainly the URL called and optionally how it was called (eg, from a `store.findAll()` or `store.queryRecord()`, etc.). Is there a single place (my guess is somewhere in `adapter:application`?) where I can put a single `console.log('URL called: ', url, ', from: ', callingFunction);` that handles all of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `JSONAPIAdapter` or the `RESTAdapter` just override `ajax()` on the adapter to log the URI:

```
ajax(url, type, options) {
  console.log(url);
  return this._super(...arguments);
}
```

There is no easy way to get the caller function. Analyse the callstack, if its just for debugging purposes!
But, maybe just use the Browser `log XMLHttpRequest` option if its for debugging?!

If you want to know how it works, checkout the code. The adapter and the store is where you can look for knowledge.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. But I did have to modify your code to `return this._super(...arguments);` since I was getting an error without the `return`